# How to generate 3 page pay slip data on one page, using TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

now i use `TCPDF` to generate dynamic pay slip for every person per page. Now i want to generate `3` pay slip per page using `TCPDF`,`PHP`.Please help me.

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add to your loop:

```
for($x=0; $x<count($records); $x++ ) {
if( mod(x,3) == 0 ) pdf->addPage();
//--- do pdf stuff
}
```